# Not able to fetch json data in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, json, ruby-on-rails-3, get

This is my code in my view where I am making an ajax get request to method `campaign_creation`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submit").click(function(){
        $.get("/configure_campaign/campaign_creation",{category_name: $("#category_name").val()}, function(data){

            $("#category_name").val('');
            $("#form_add_category").css("display","none");
            alert(data.category_name)

        })
    })
})
```

and here is my method code

```
def campaign_creation
    if(params[:page_id] and params[:page_access_token])

        abcd=params[:page_id].split("_")
        session[:page_id]=abcd[0]
        session[:page_access_token] = params[:page_access_token]

    else

        category=Category.new
        category.category_name=params[:category_name]
        category.page_id=session[:page_id]
        category.save
        @category=Category.find(1)
        @category.to_json

    end
end
```

I think I should be able to access `@category` in my variable data. If I simply put data in my alert box I get the complete code of the page and if `data.category_name` I get the result as undefined.

Comment: Post logs and/or errors, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the code you've provided for your action alone, you're not going to be rendering a JSON response. Your `campaign_creation` method is going to try and find a `campaign_creation.html.erb` file and render a `text/html` response.

Instead you need to explicitly tell Rails to render JSON data and the end of the action and stop processing.

```
render json: @category and return
```

**Now** you can expect the `data` variable in your Ajax response to have accesss to the `@campaign`'s `:category_name` attribute.

Comment: Thank you so much. this works. I have another question. Say instead of just our object containing just one row like here. it contains more than one row. For eg. we had @categories=Category.where(..) which returns multiple rows. how could we send that in a json response and handle it in our jQuery.. ?

Comment: I strongly recommend you check out the **[active_model_serializers](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers)** gem. It is well documented and will make passing complex JSON to the frontend a simple task.